# Set Nav Bar's Title From Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a rootTableView with cells that are loaded from an array:

```
logArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"John", @"Jack", @"Jill", nil];
```

When I click a cell, for example the cell called "Jack", it will take me to a sub table for "Jack"

How to I set the title of that sub tableView to "Jack", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the tableView delegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NextViewController *nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];


**nextView.title = [logArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];**


//push the nextView here

}
```

Comment: This works but there is a slight delay with loading the subview's title.  Any idea why?  Like the nav bar loads first, then the title loads.  I would like it to load at the same time.

Comment: nevermind got it working fine. just added the title code before the push code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using the `UITableView` section header for this

Comment: The line is `self.navigationItem.title = @"Test";` but I don't know what to set it to.

Comment: @Faisal: Sorry I don't get you.

Comment: I have a table view, the cells are populated by the code in my org question.  When I click a cell, the next sub view's nav bar title should be the name of the cell that was clicked.  Like if the first table has categories: rap, pop, rock, dance, country - if you click a cell, the next table should have songs in that category but the nav bar title should be that genre, so dance, pop, rap, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a property in your sub tableview that you can pass the name along to. Something like this should be in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
UITableViewCell *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
MySubtableviewController *mstvc = [[MySubTsbleViewController alloc] init];
mstvc.nameProperty = currentCell.textLabel.text;

[self.navigstiomController pushViewController:mstvc];
```

Something like that where the nameProperty is declared in your sub tableView controller. 
Then in your sub view controller, just set the title in viewDidLoad.

```
self.title = self.nameProperty;
```

Hope this helps.